# Vector transformations in OpenGL ES

Tags: vector, opengl-es, transform

Why are vector transformations done in reverse order in OpenGL ES? Is it because the vectors are stored in column-matrix form? It seems that they have made things unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the fact that vector transformations aren't commutative.  Changing the order can give you a different result.

A simple thought experiment proves the point:

1. For a unit vector (1, 0, 0), a +90 degree rotation about the z-axis, followed by a +90 degree rotation about the x-axis results in a vector (0, 0, 1).
2. If you start with the +90 degree rotation about the x-axis, followed by the +90 degree rotation about the z-axis, you'll have a vector (0, 1, 0).

Comment: I know it's not commutative. I want to know why it's done backwards.

Comment: "backwards" implies that there is a "forwards" direction that you think is more correct.  Can you clarify this?